# CircleCI - pushing to github during build phase fails due to read-only key

Tags: javascript, build, circleci

I am trying to push a successful build to github but CircleCI alerts me that the key to github is readonly. What can I do?

[image]

The Github key is read-only but it cannot be changed and it was created by circleCI:

[image]

My deploy_staging.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
gulp
cd staging
git init
git checkout -b "staging"
git config user.name "circleci"
git config user.email "circleci@aaa.org.il"
git add . -A
git commit -m "build"
git remote add azure https://github.com/aaa/webogram.git
git push azure staging --force
```

Gulp is creating a new directory - "staging" - and builds the project into it. I then want to push the outcome to azure so I am trying to use a new branch ("staging") and pushing only the build directory to it.

Comment: To make that happen you’ll need to add a new deploy key to your project that would have the right permissions. Please review [this doc](https://circleci.com/docs/github-security-ssh-keys) for details on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same task today in [this project](https://github.com/urbanmassage/performance-tests).

Basically you need to follow the instructions [here](https://circleci.com/docs/adding-read-write-deployment-key). i.e. add a private key to circle project settings.